# CSS display flex preventing colspan from working as expected when dynamically showing/hiding the table row

Tags: css, flexbox

In the case where the body of an HTML page is set to `display: flex;` Is there a way that a table row that uses `colspan` can be shown/hidden with JavaScript/jQuery?

In the following example, when the hidden table row is shown the `<td colspan="5">` only expands to fill one column instead of the expected 5.

```js
$('#click_me').click(function() {
  $('#hidden').toggle();
});
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
}

#hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
  </head>
   <body>
    <table class="table">

      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>Foo</td>
          <td>Bar</td>
          <td>Foo</td>
          <td>Bar</td>
          <td>Foo</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>A <a id="click_me" href="javascript:;">Click</a></td>
          <td>B</td>
          <td>C</td>
          <td>D</td>
          <td>E</td>
        </tr>

        <tr id="hidden">
          <td colspan="5">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because of using `toggle()` function.

When using `toggle()` function, it toggles from `block` <=> `none`.

And the default `display` css attribute of `<tr>` selector is `table-row` and `colspan` will work on that display `attribute` only.

To resolve that, use `toggleClass` function instead and define a new class named `.show` that contains `display: table-row` as follows.

```js
$('#click_me').click(function() {
  $('#hidden').toggleClass('show');
});
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
}

#hidden {
  display: none;
}

#hidden.show {
  display: table-row;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
  </head>
   <body>
    <table class="tabhttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/64565810/css-display-flex-preventing-colspan-from-working-as-expected-when-dynamically-sh#le">

      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>Foo</td>
          <td>Bar</td>
          <td>Foo</td>
          <td>Bar</td>
          <td>Foo</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>A <a id="click_me" href="javascript:;">Click</a></td>
          <td>B</td>
          <td>C</td>
          <td>D</td>
          <td>E</td>
        </tr>

        <tr id="hidden">
          <td colspan="5">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```